# Sample weather app getting force close

Tags: android, weather

I am new for this application and i am following tutorials to learn. I followed https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/tree/master/WeatherForecastApp to test weather app but i am getting force close. I also goggled for this error but still i am not able to solve. If anybody faced this error please help.

Logcat error

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp/com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp-2.apk]
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp-2.apk]
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5988):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: check menifest activity define or not.

Comment: Can you please post your Manifest file?

Comment: i guess the manifest is the one in gh https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/tree/master/WeatherForecastApp

Comment: have you actually imported the MainActivity java file in the correct package from github projecT?

Comment: clean the project..and try again..

Comment: project cleaned, no changes. yes imported the correct project from github

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you didn't download correctly the project from GitHub. If you stil experience this problem let me know and will try to download it from Github to check if there are some problems with the project i shared.
Thank you